# Re-render Server Component every X seconds

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

I have a server component that reads from the database:

```
import { db } from "@utils/database";

export async function UsersLayout() {
  let users = await db.query(...);
  // ...

  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map(user => 
        <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

How can I make this component re-render every 60 seconds? Since this is a server component I cannot use `useEffect` and `setTimeout`...

I'm playing around with [Nextjs.13](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/fundamentals)

Comment: Forget re-rendering every `60` seconds, you cannot re-render a server component, since it cannot have `useState`(https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#moving-client-components-to-the-leaves). You can think of them as PHP-style code, but in JSX.  See [https://www.shivamjha.io/blog/react-server-components#when-not-to-use-server-components-](When to not use Server Components)

Comment: @ShivamJha thanks for the blog article. I don't understand one thing - I've read that you can interleave Server and Client Components. So if the server component is nested under the client component then by updating the client component, server component should re-render?

Comment: Server Components can be nested inside child component [as children only](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#importing-server-components-into-client-components). So, the server component will be just sent as plain HTML & CSS. You can confirm this by adding a console inside the parent server component & check re-rendering the children (Client Component) in the browser

Comment: This may help you out: https://twitter.com/leeerob/status/1607475053351813120?s=20&t=15GWhrcWNh5jLT9DhbvoDQ

Comment: Google sent me here as well. Still pretty confused on how to do this. Anyone else find an easier solution?